# Is there a way to designate a default property of a class?

Tags: c#, properties

I wonder if there is a way to designate a default property of a class in C#.

For example, if I have the class below:

```
class NewType
{
    public object Value 
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            IsInitialized = true;
            _value = value;
        }
    }
    public bool IsInitialized { get; private set; }

    // ... etc properties
}
```

I want to use the above class as follows:

```
void Test()
{
    NewType Value = new NewType();

    // The follow assignment expression means 'Value.Value = 10;'
    Value = 10;
}
```

I don't know if the above idea is good but I think it can improve readability in my case.

Is there a way to achieve this goal?

Comment: `NewType Value = new NewType() { Value = 10 };` is likely the closest you will get.

Comment: I want to use 'Value = 10' expression outside of constructor.

Comment: Not really.  Only the indexer can be the default property.  Square brackets required, like Value[0] = 10.

Comment: @jjw What's wrong with `Value.Value = 10;`? You probably should choose a better name for the variable though. What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve here? This sounds like a case of [The XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Maybe if you tell us what your end goal is, someone could suggest a better approach.

Comment: The sticking point is likely your use of `=`. Even if you manage to get this to work (e.g. with implicit conversion) then the code won't be equivalent to `Value.Value = 10`. It will be equivalent to `Value = new NewType() { Value = 10 };` (i.e. lose the values of all of the other properties).

Comment: c# doesn't have default properties like vb did.

Comment: I want to use NewType class as normal type.
for example "int a = 10". in my case equals  "a.Value = 10".

Comment: What you are suggesting exists in VBA but not C# or VB.Net. As AFAIK, you cannot achieve that in C#.

Comment: @DanielA.White AFAIK, Default Properties in VB are Indexers in C#. One can't declare a default property without a required parameter. Edit: Oh, maybe you're referring to classic VB and VBA.

Comment: I come to know that only Indexer can achieve the above goal. The answers helped me much. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In answer to your question about a "default property", the answer is no. The best you can do is specify the property whose value you want to assign:

```
var newType = new NewType {Value = 10};
```

The next best thing is to create a constructor that sets the value:

```
class NewType
{
    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            IsInitialized = true;
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsInitialized { get; private set; }

    public NewType(int value) 
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    // ... etc properties
}
```

And now there's slightly less typing:

```
var newType = new NewType(10);
```

If you want to be able to initialize your class based on an integer without calling the constructor, you can implement an implicit operator for `int`, and create a new instance of your class from the assigned value:

```
class NewType
{
    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            IsInitialized = true;
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsInitialized { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator NewType(int i) => new NewType {Value = i};

    // ... etc properties
}
```

And now you can do:

```
NewType newType = 10;
```

The problem here is that if you already have a class with some other properties set and then you use the implicit operator to try to set `Value`, you actually reassign the whole object and the other properties will be set back to their default values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I realized this way is better way rather than indexer by a few experiment in my case. Thank you.